# Install {{listen}} template on Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I have installed `MediaWiki` and I would like to use the `{{listen}}` template as one can do on Wikipedia.

I tried copying the `{{Template:Listen}}` and `{{Module:Listen}}` pages onto my wiki, but it doesn't give any result as the pages are interpreted as text `(while {{Module:Listen}} is code (Lua?))`.

What should I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the extension [Scribunto](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aScribunto), to be able to use Lua. In recent MW versions, the extensions is already bundled, and all you have to do is

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/Scribunto/Scribunto.php";
```

Otherwise download it and put it in your extensions directory first.

If that doesn't work, you  might have to use another version of Lua than the one bundled with the Scribuntu extension (this will depend on your server). See instructions on [http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aScribunto) on how to do this. In short: Install Lua on your server, set `$wgScribuntoEngineConf['luastandalone']['luaPath']` to the path of your Lua binaries, and add  `$wgScribuntoDefaultEngine = 'luastandalone';` after the require_once line.